# MVVM Light ViewModelLocator in separate assembly ? Design time mode issue

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm-light

I'm using MVVM Light V4 with Ninject. My ViewModel files are in separate assembly. It works great when ViewModelLocator is in start assembly (View files). Blendability works.

I want to place ViewModelLocator in ViewModel assembly, but when i do it, I'm loosing blendability. After that it's working properly only in started application (not in design time mode).

ViewModelLocator:

```
static ViewModelLocator()
    {
        ServiceLocator.Initialize();

        if (ViewModelBase.IsInDesignModeStatic)
        {
            using (var module = new DesignBindingsModule())
            {
                ServiceLocator.Load(module);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            using (var module = new DefaultBindingsModule())
            {
                ServiceLocator.Load(module);
            }
        }
    }

[System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Performance",
        "CA1822:MarkMembersAsStatic",
        Justification = "This non-static member is needed for data binding purposes.")]
    public IMainWindowViewModel MainWindow
    {
        get
        {
            return ServiceLocator.Get<IMainWindowViewModel>();
        }
    }
```

Is it possible to put ViewModelLocator in separate assembly and bind to it in design time mode?

Comment: one thing I may do when having trouble with the designer is throw exceptions to see what code is executing.  For instance, you may want to see the return value of `ServiceLocator.Get<IMainWindowViewModel>();
`.  throw ServiceLocator.Get<IMainWindowViewModel>().ToString() or something..

Comment: you should submit it as an answer and accept OR delete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. I had a bug in code. ServiceLocator was initialized two times, and throw an exception, which unable to proper binding. It's strange that it only occurs in designer, and designer doesn't show exception. I refactor the code and problem disappeared. I have all ViewModel relative classes in separate assembly.